# Checking login credentials against a MongoDB is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongodb-query

```
router.post('/checkuser', function(req, res) {

    var db = req.db;

    var userEmail = req.body.useremail;
    var password = req.body.password;

    var collection = db.get('usercollection');

    collection.find( { "email": userEmail }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err || !doc) {
            res.redirect("login");
        } else {
            res.redirect("userlist");
        }
    });
});
```

This code is supposed to check the login credentials in a MongoDB and return `false` if the values are not matched.

But it always redirects to the `userlist.jade` file. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: why you dont add password in condition? any reason?

Comment: You need to use `findOne`, `find` will return a cursor. And as suggested by @Dineshaws checking the password might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code always redirects to the `userlist.jade` file because of the current logic in the callback function: since **[`find()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#find)** method returns a cursor, the if statement checks whether there is an error **OR** there is no returned cursor with the matched document, thus the variable doc is a cursor which is always returned whether there is a match or not. Use the [**`findOne()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOne) method instead:

```
collection.findOne({"email": userEmail}, function(err, user) {
    if( !err && user && user.password === password ) {
        res.redirect("userlist");
    }
    else { res.redirect("login"); }
});
```

Comment: I would also strongly recommend to use `bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)` to hash the password and the use of `bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)` to compare the provided password with the stored password hash.

Comment: @Jaco Great suggestion, would strongly recommend that too!